# Pattern matching simple types

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, miranda

I am a beginner trying to learn functional programming.

Is there a way to pattern match different standard (not user defined) types?

E.g. if the argument of the function is a tuple, add them, if it is just an int, use int:

```
form (x, y) = x + y
form any_num = any_num
```

This obviously won't work, because the program thinks any_num is just any tuple and is therefore unreachable.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with standard vs user-defined types. The issue is that Haskell functions can only accept a *single, consistent type* as input. You cannot have one case of a function that uses one type and another case of a function that uses a different type.

Comment: Ok thanks, if that is the case. I guess I have to take another approach.

Comment: Generally, if you want a function to accept two types of data, you tag them using a sum type. For example, you could write `data IntOrTuple = I Int | T (Int, Int)`, then write a function from `IntOrTuple -> Int`.

Comment: Overloading and type classes also seem relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may do as follows;

```
form :: Either (Int,Int) Int -> Int

form (Left (n,m)) = n + m
form (Right n)    = n

>> form (Left (2,3))
>> 5
>> form (Right 7)
>> 7
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a [type class](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses). We can define the class of `Formable` types that have a `form` function:

```
class Formable a where
    form :: a -> Int
```

For ints, just use the int

```
instance Formable Int where
    form x = x
```

If the argument is a tuple, add its arguments together. I'm going to go one step further, and instead of only working on tuples `(Int, Int)` its formable instance will work on any tuple `(a, b)` as long as both `a` and `b` are `Formable`

```
instance (Formable a, Formable b) => Formable (a, b) where
    form (a, b) = form a + form b
```

---

We can write `Formable` instances for other types in a similar vein. Like totaling the elements of a list

```
instance (Formable a) => Formable [a] where
    form = sum . map form
```

or the alternatives of a sum

```
instance (Formable a, Formable b) => Formable (Either a b) where
    form (Left a) = form a
    form (Right b) = form b
```

or even `Maybe`, if we know what to do with `Nothing`

```
instance (Formable a) => Formable (Maybe a) where
    form Nothing = 0
    form (Just a) = form a
```

Answer (score 0):

In Miranda, function must be of given type. For example:

Your first line:

```
form (x, y) = x + y
```

has type:

```
form :: (num,num) -> num
```

There are two solutions:

1. Use abstract type with alternative cases
2. Use dynamic FP language (I like Erlang).